# Would you demand a proof that this is a cyclic subgroup of $(Z/NZ, *)$?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, article-writing

I'm mostly looking for advice on how to say, how to write this, how to prove it.  I think it probably dispenses a proof.  I'm writing this to a small number-theory audience, so I don't think they need much of anything here, but perhaps I could be in need of some help myself.

**The prose**. Take any *iterated* linear polynomial of integer coefficients such as one from the family

$$f(x) = ax \bmod{N}$$

with $1 < a \bmod{N}$ for some fixed natural number $a$ coprime with $N$.  It is easy to see that any such polynomial from this family has closed-form formula $g(i) = a^i \bmod{N}$.  Since $g$ generates a subgroup of $(Z/NZ, *)$, then we know that the length of the cycle of $g$ is the order of $a$ modulo $N$.

---

Should I prove this more formally?  Because the closed-form formula is trivially obtained, we can also easily see that $a$ generates the set $\{a, a^2, a^3, ..., a^{r - 1}, a^r = 1\}$.  Therefore, $f$ generates a cyclic subgroup of $(Z/ZN, *)$ with generator $a$.

Thank you for any thoughts.

**An example**.  Choose $a = 2$ and $N = 15$ so that $f(x) = 2x \bmod{15}$.  Let $x_0 = 1$. If we iterate $f$, we get the values $1, 2, 4, 8, 1, ...$.  So, clearly, the closed-form formula for $f$ is $g(i) = 2^i \bmod{15}$, which suggests that $2$ is a generator for the subgroup {1, 2, 4, 8} of $(Z/15Z, *) = \{1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14\}$.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  How is $f(x)$ a "family"?  What is the connection between $f(x)$ and $g(i)$?  More importantly, $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$ is not a group under multiplication.  If you meant to speak of the invertible elements of that ring then you needed some conditions on $a$.

Comment: It's a family in the sense that different numbers $a$ produce different linear polynomials.  The connection between $f(x)$ and $g(i)$ is that $g(i)$ is the closed-form formula for $f(x)$.  The polynomial $f$ is iterated: you start with some initial number $x_0$, compute $f(x_0)$ and then $f(f(x_0))$ and so on, which means that to find out which number is $x_n$ you will need to invoke $f$ $n$ times.  But using $g$, you get $x_n = g(n) = a^n \bmod{N}$.  Does that make sense?  I'll update the question with an example.  Thank you.

Comment: No, it doesn't really make sense.  $f(x)$ is a single function, not a collection of them. Your post never mentioned that you were iterating $f$.  I can't imagine that anyone would have guessed that.  And, as I mentioned, your algebraic structure is not a group so it does not have subgroups.

Comment: Anyway, I think you were asking if your discussion was clear or not, and I think that the answer is that it is not.

Comment: Thanks for your corrections.  I'm emphasizing that $f$ is iterated now.

Comment: Again, $g(i)$ is not the closed form formula for $f(x)$.  $g(i)$ is what you get if you start at $1$ and apply $f$ $i$ times.  But, really, the group thing is important. If $N=15$ and you take $a=3$ instead of $a=2$, you never get back to $1$.  Your iterates go $\{1,3,9,12, 6, 3, 9, 12, 6, \cdots\}$

Comment: Thank you --- I must say that $a$ must be coprime with $N$.  Question updated.